# ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed() Failed

Tags: directx, directx-11

my program is Directx Program that draws a container cube within it smaller cubes....these smaller cubes fall by time i hope you understand what i mean...

**The program isn't complete yet ...it should draws the container only ....but it draws nothing ...only the background color is visible... i only included what i think is needed ...**

this is the routines that initialize the program

```
bool Game::init(HINSTANCE hinst,HWND _hw){
Directx11 ::init(hinst , _hw);
return LoadContent();}
```

Directx11::init()

```
bool Directx11::init(HINSTANCE hinst,HWND hw){
_hinst=hinst;_hwnd=hw;
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(_hwnd,&rc);
height= rc.bottom - rc.top;
width = rc.right - rc.left;
UINT flags=0;
#ifdef _DEBUG
flags |=D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif
HR(D3D11CreateDevice(0,_driverType,0,flags,0,0,D3D11_SDK_VERSION,&d3dDevice,&_featureLevel,&d3dDeviceContext));
if (d3dDevice == 0 || d3dDeviceContext == 0)
    return 0;
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sdesc;
ZeroMemory(&sdesc,sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));
sdesc.Windowed=true;
sdesc.BufferCount=1;
sdesc.BufferDesc.Format=DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
sdesc.BufferDesc.Height=height;
sdesc.BufferDesc.Width=width;
sdesc.BufferDesc.Scaling=DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;
sdesc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering=DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
sdesc.OutputWindow=_hwnd;
sdesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator=1;
sdesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator=60;
sdesc.Flags=0;
sdesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
if (m4xMsaaEnable)
{
    sdesc.SampleDesc.Count=4;
    sdesc.SampleDesc.Quality=m4xMsaaQuality-1;
}
else
{
    sdesc.SampleDesc.Count=1;
    sdesc.SampleDesc.Quality=0;
}
IDXGIDevice *Device=0;
HR(d3dDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice),reinterpret_cast <void**> (&Device)));
IDXGIAdapter*Ad=0;
HR(Device->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter),reinterpret_cast <void**> (&Ad)));
IDXGIFactory* fac=0;
HR(Ad->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory),reinterpret_cast <void**> (&fac)));
fac->CreateSwapChain(d3dDevice,&sdesc,&swapchain);
ReleaseCOM(Device);
ReleaseCOM(Ad);
ReleaseCOM(fac);
ID3D11Texture2D *back = 0;
HR(swapchain->GetBuffer(0,__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D),reinterpret_cast <void**> (&back)));
HR(d3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(back,0,&RenderTarget));
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC Tdesc;
ZeroMemory(&Tdesc,sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
Tdesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
Tdesc.ArraySize = 1;
Tdesc.Format= DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
Tdesc.Height= height;
Tdesc.Width = width;
Tdesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
Tdesc.MipLevels=1;
if (m4xMsaaEnable)
{
    Tdesc.SampleDesc.Count=4;
    Tdesc.SampleDesc.Quality=m4xMsaaQuality-1;
}
else
{
    Tdesc.SampleDesc.Count=1;
    Tdesc.SampleDesc.Quality=0;
}
HR(d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&Tdesc,0,&depthview));
HR(d3dDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(depthview,0,&depth));
d3dDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1,&RenderTarget,depth);
D3D11_VIEWPORT vp;
vp.TopLeftX=0.0f;
vp.TopLeftY=0.0f;
vp.Width = static_cast <float> (width);
vp.Height= static_cast <float> (height);
vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
d3dDeviceContext -> RSSetViewports(1,&vp);
return true;
```

**SetBuild() Prepare the matrices inside the container for the smaller cubes ....i didnt program it to draw the smaller cubes yet**

and this the function that draws the scene

```
void Game::Render(){
d3dDeviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(RenderTarget,reinterpret_cast <const float*> (&Colors::LightSteelBlue));
d3dDeviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView(depth,D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL,1.0f,0);

d3dDeviceContext-> IASetInputLayout(_layout);
d3dDeviceContext-> IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
d3dDeviceContext->IASetIndexBuffer(indices,DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT,0);
UINT strides=sizeof(Vertex),off=0;
d3dDeviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0,1,&vertices,&strides,&off);

D3DX11_TECHNIQUE_DESC des;
Tech->GetDesc(&des);
Floor * Lookup;                 /*is a variable to Lookup inside the matrices structure (Floor Contains      XMMATRX Piese[9])*/
std::vector<XMFLOAT4X4> filled; // saves the matrices of the smaller cubes
XMMATRIX V=XMLoadFloat4x4(&View),P = XMLoadFloat4x4(&Proj);
XMMATRIX vp = V * P;XMMATRIX wvp;
for (UINT i = 0; i < des.Passes; i++)
{
    d3dDeviceContext->RSSetState(BuildRast);
    wvp = XMLoadFloat4x4(&(B.Memory[0].Pieces[0])) * vp; // Loading The Matrix at translation(0,0,0) 

    HR(ShadeMat->SetMatrix(reinterpret_cast<float*> ( &wvp)));
    HR(Tech->GetPassByIndex(i)->Apply(0,d3dDeviceContext));
    d3dDeviceContext->DrawIndexed(build_ind_count,build_ind_index,build_vers_index);

    d3dDeviceContext->RSSetState(PieseRast);
    UINT r1=B.GetSize(),r2=filled.size();
    for (UINT j = 0; j < r1; j++)
    {
        Lookup = &B.Memory[j];
        for (UINT r = 0; r < Lookup->filledindeces.size(); r++)
        {
            filled.push_back(Lookup->Pieces[Lookup->filledindeces[r]]);
        }
    }
    for (UINT j = 0; j < r2; j++)
    {
        ShadeMat->SetMatrix( reinterpret_cast<const float*> (&filled[i]));
        Tech->GetPassByIndex(i)->Apply(0,d3dDeviceContext);
        d3dDeviceContext->DrawIndexed(piese_ind_count,piese_ind_index,piese_vers_index);
    }
}
HR(swapchain->Present(0,0));}
```

thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you run with the Debug Runtime? When creating the device, you can ask for the debug runtime, which will give you quite verbose output that should help you to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: yes i used it but no error yet nothing visible render target outpot background

Answer (score 1):

One bug in your program appears to be that you're using `i`, the index of the current pass, as an index into the `filled` vector, when you should apparently be using `j`.

Another apparent bug is that in the loop where you are supposed to be iterating over the elements of `filled`, you're not iterating over all of them. The value `r2` is set to the size of `filled` before you append anything to it during that pass. During the first pass this means that nothing will be drawn by this loop. If your technique only has one pass then this means that the second `DrawIndexed` call in your code will never be executed.

It also appears you should be only adding matrices to `filled` once, regardless of the number of the passes the technique has. You should consider if your code is actually meant to work with techniques with multiple passes.

Comment: i intended to use filled empty because i didn't prepare the smaller cubes meshes ...the i usage is really a bug but that isn't the main cause of the problem ....i found the real cause....it is in a function i didn't included....the problem is std::vector initialize itself with some values when you use it like this `std::vector<AnyType> var(size)` those values corrupted the index buffer....thanks you nailed a bug i wouldn't easily find ....